# How to use client-side validation to work on your asp.net mvc in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have client-side validation using jQuery to validate when there is an empty space for my `@EditorFor()` controls. However when I filter any data the error does not disappear.

I also need some examples within my logic as when the error pops in it must be displayed with an image in the center, currently it's to the side.

```
// Model
     [Required]
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CellNumber { get; set; }

// View

<div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="ZipCode" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegForm.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "ZipCode", id = "textZipCode" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegForm.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <label id="labelMessage_zip" class="text-danger" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegForm.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Email", id = "textEmail" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegForm.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <label id="labelMessage_email" class="text-danger" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Attendee" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Attendee Cell Number*</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegForm.CellNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Cell Number", id ="textCellNumber" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegForm.CellNumber)
                                </div>
                                <label id="labelMessage_cell" class="text-danger" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
                            </div>
```

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/dist/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

            <!--Handling form-validation when empty-->
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(function () {
                    //When the blur event occurs from your Textbox (you lose focus)
                    $('#textEmail').blur(function () {
                        var email = document.getElementById("textEmail").value;
                        var expr = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/;
                        if (!expr.test(email)) {
                            document.getElementById("labelMessage_email").style.display = "inline";
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("labelMessage_email").style.display = "none";
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Error message for cell-phone.
                $(function () {
                    $('#textCellNumber').blur(function () {
                        var cell = document.getElementById("textCellNumber").value;
                        var expr = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/;
                        if (!expr.test(cell)) {
                            document.getElementById("labelMessage_cell").style.display = "inline";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("labelMessage_cell").style.display = "none";
                        }
                    });

                });


                // Error message for ZipCode.
                $(function () {
                    $('#textZipCode').blur(function () {
                        var zipcode = document.getElementById("textZipCode").value;
                        var expr = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/;
                        if (!expr.test(zipcode)) {
                            document.getElementById("labelMessage_zip").style.display = "inline";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("labelMessage_zip").style.display = "none";
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Simply do it with Unobtrusive validation provided by MVC. Add jaquery reference for Unobtrusive validation.

Comment: any examples i can use perhaps?

Comment: Further assistance is provided in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use these libraries:

```
"~/Content/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"
"~/Content/assets/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
```

And in your model write attribute above the properties as:

```
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Use library for attributes: `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: Ok Imran let me work it now provide feedback if necessary, thanks.

Comment: you see there is a small problem, the email is only one working. Meaning when there is an email the error dissapear, unlike zipCode and CellNumber. They dont seem to work. Let me show you my logic within this topic.

Comment: Here is the detailed example to apply unobtrusive validation https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/